# Etag's are not being taken out of css,js, and images?

Tags: .htaccess, compression, etag, yslow

I'm attempting to reduce the loading speed of my site by using mod_deflate and mod_headers, which compresses the content and sets expire dates but also deletes the ETag's for my content. It is not however deleting the ETags from my images (png's), css, and js according to Yslow.

My .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$            HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule filter_module>
        FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
        FilterChain     COMPRESS
        FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
        # Legacy versions of Apache
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 month" 
    ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
```

Taken from: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Check the headers yourself. Could be that YSlow is wrong. Could be that your browser's cache is messing things up.

Comment: Use chrome. Under Developer Tools use the Network tab. Or in firefox use Firebugs net tab

Comment: You can also check the headers with [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), for example `curl --head http://www.example.com/file.png`, and look for the ETag header in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out..

YSlow was caching the results. Changing browsers (from Safari to Firefox) seemed to show that the ETags were in fact deleted.

Comment: Charlie, you may want to "accept" your own answer here so this shows as being resolved.